# Can I use dependence injection with template-like class in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I'm working with the Laravel 5.2 framework and looking for a very easy way to safely define authorization for all routes. We use dependency injection for the Request **authorization**.

For example, the controller looks like:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(MyRequest $request)
    {
    }
}
```

We have extended the FormRequest class so that we can define authorization with a simple string.

```
class MyRequest extends CustomRequest
{
    protected $permissions = 'perm-name';
}
```

We have also defined the behaviour if you forget to specify $permissions is crash (happens in CustomRequest). This way, we know that all routes that have a request have an authorized request (this is a key design requirement).

The problem with this approach is that we need one request class for every handled permission, even if the only difference is the name of the permission.

If this was some magic "PHP with C++ class templates", I think the following would make sense and reduce a lot of repeated code:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(TemplateRequest<'perm-name'> $request)
    {
    }
}

template <PERM_NAME> class TemplateRequest extends CustomRequest
{
    protected $permissions = PERM_NAME;
}
```

In this case, all requests that only need to specify the permission only need to specify the name.

As far as I can tell, this isn't possible. Can someone prove me wrong?